# Getting an XML error when launching WordPress Android App

Tags: wordpress

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@xxxxxx)
```

How can I fix it on my end?

Comment: what operations do you do on the android app to cause the problem? It looks like the application is reading an xml from somewhere and the file is truncated.

Comment: Just trying to set up the app with my blog url and password (logging in for the first time)

Comment: You may try to upgrade your server Wordpress. Maybe it's older than supported by the android app.